# Similar libraries to react-query for angular

Tags: angular, react-query

I have been working with both react and angular for quite some time and I encountered react-query, which is a very handy library.

So, for people who are wondering about the use case, react-query offers caching, infinite-query(Greatly helps with infinite scrolling or pagination), and retries on queries after intervals. I wish to achieve all this efficiently the same way react-query does.

Are there any similar well-maintained libraries for angular as well?
Suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: What is your use case ?

Comment: I have updated the question, I just wish to have an alternate since I can't use react query with angular.

Comment: https://github.com/timdeschryver/rx-query

Comment: There is a new wrapper in Angular for TanStack Query. Take a look! https://github.com/ngneat/query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of recommendations

- A good Graphql and over all rest consuming client [Apollo
  Angular](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apollo-angular)
- [Caching with Apollo - Ex:](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-configuration/)
- [Infinite scrolling in Apollo - Ex:](https://www.apollographql.com/blog/apollo-client/pagination/pagination-and-infinite-scrolling/)
- Beside you can code using [rxjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxjs) + Angular HttpModule as well, Ex: [Infinite Scrolling](https://blog.strongbrew.io/infinite-scroll-with-rxjs-and-angular2/), [Caching](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2018/03/05/advanced-caching-with-rxjs.html)

Comment: @wobsoriano rx-query is no longer being actively maintained.